# Objective-C : Title of tab bar item will not change after login page but works when relaunch from xCode?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have a `Change Language VC` that changes the language of the app. 
If I initially run the app, register and log in. Then immediately I go to the `change language VC` and hit the `change language method`. The title of the tab bar item will still remains and not will not trigger. Please check out the link [Please focus on the title of the tab bar item](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vY8DTxt2Ho&feature=youtu.be)

However if relaunch the app in xCode and it is at the initial page or `Home VC` and not from the log in page and I go to the `change language VC`, everything works fine. Please check out the link and [Please focus on the title of the tab bar item](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ILzcVnavjDo&feature=youtu.be)

To all the gurus out there, please help me, i want the title of the tab bar item to change. Thanks.

## StoryBoard

[image: StoryBoard]

## Localized.cn.strings

```
"Home" = "主页";

"News" = "新闻";

"Class" = "课程";

"Gym" = "健身房";

"More" = "更多";

"CHANGE LANGUAGE" = "更改语言";
```

## LoginVC

```
- (void)dismissLoginAndShowProfile {

    AppDelegate *authObj = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    authObj.authenticated = YES;

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileView"];
    tabView.selectedIndex=0; //=== This is to choose which Tab, starts with 0,1,2,3,4
    [self presentViewController:tabView animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

## AppsDelegate.m (AppsDelegate will call the about table and get the title accordingly)

```
+ (NSString*)getCurrentLang {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *sLanguage = [defaults objectForKey:@"txtLanguage"];
    if(sLanguage == nil) {
        return @"EN";
    }else{
        return sLanguage;
    }
}

//=== This method will getCurrentLang and concatanate with Localizable_cn or en
+ (NSString*)getLocalizedTableName {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Localizable_%@",[[self    getCurrentLang]lowercaseString]];
}

//=== This method will call getLocalizedTableName, 
+ (NSString*)getLocalizedText:(NSString*)toLocalize {
    return NSLocalizedStringFromTable(toLocalize, [AppDelegate getLocalizedTableName], @"");
}

//=== Change Language VC will call the following method
//=== the Method will can getLocatlizedText method and pass @"Home" to it
- (void)setupTabBar {

    UITabBarController * tabBarController = (UITabBarController*)[self.window rootViewController];

    if(tabBarController != nil) {
        ((UIViewController*)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]).tabBarItem.title = [AppDelegate getLocalizedText:@"Home"];
        ((UIViewController*)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1]).tabBarItem.title = [AppDelegate getLocalizedText:@"News"];
        ((UIViewController*)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:2]).tabBarItem.title = [AppDelegate getLocalizedText:@"Class"];
        ((UIViewController*)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:3]).tabBarItem.title = [AppDelegate getLocalizedText:@"Gym"];
        ((UIViewController*)[tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:4]).tabBarItem.title =  [AppDelegate getLocalizedText:@"More"];
    }
}
```

## ProfileChgLang.m (I only show the button Change to Chinese button method)

```
- (IBAction)btnChinese:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:@"CN" forKey:@"txtLanguage"];

    [(AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate setupTabBar];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = self.navigationController;
    [navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: getCurrentLang method sLanguage what you are getting?

Comment: add [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; in btnChinese method  because NSUserDefaults may not always work:

Comment: The NSUserDefaults is working I have tried to check the language. It does work

Comment: what you are getting sLanguage when you coming from homevc

Comment: I am getting EN. The thing that I suspect that make the app crazy is when log in I present another view controller with the following code. 

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileView"];
    tabView.selectedIndex=0; //=== This is to choose which Tab, starts with 0,1,2,3,4
    [self presentViewController:tabView animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: In btnChinese you are changing to CN right.That time what you are getting sLanguage

Comment: At that instance, I will get CN in userdefault, then the button called the AppDelegate method setupTabBar. Everything works but setupTabBar during the initial log in will not trigger.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179893/discussion-between-rajesh-dharani-and-hanz-cheah).

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: Yes @ReinierMelian I have, thanks. If you have time can you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52293432/objective-c-how-to-properly-set-didselectviewcontroller-method-for-tabbarcontro/52299231#52299231 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306981/objective-c-tabbaritem-tapped-method-called-but-webview-not-refreshed please?

Comment: ok, @HanzCheah I will review it

Comment: @ReinierMelian I got it to work, according to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306981/objective-c-tabbaritem-tapped-method-called-but-webview-not-refreshed Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At the LoginVC for the following method. Add the last line.

```
    - (void)dismissLoginAndShowProfile {

       AppDelegate *authObj = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
       authObj.authenticated = YES;

       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
       UITabBarController *tabView = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"profileView"];
       tabView.selectedIndex=0; //=== This is to choose which Tab, starts with 0,1,2,3,4
       [self presentViewController:tabView animated:YES completion:nil];

       [[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; //==== This is the line that is needed
    }
```